# Open browser in host system from Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: bash, browser, ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a ruby script that does contains this line:

```
system("open '#{html_path}'")
```

`html_path` is the path to a local `.html` file. So the script opens a browser where I can normally inspect and view this file.

In contrast to a MacOS environment, this doesn't work in `bash` of WSL. Running the script *nothing* happens, and when I execute the `open` call in the console directly I get this:

```
sujan@LenovoX1:/mnt/c/Users/Jan/Documents/foo$ open Preview.html
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

I already investigated that [`open` does something different in Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2124061) and I should use `see` or `xdg-open` to open a file.

Unfortunately these also don't work in WSL:

```
sujan@LenovoX1:/mnt/c/Users/Jan/Documents/foo$ see ./Preview.html
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /us
r/bin/see line 528.
Couldn't find a suitable web browser!
Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1
```

and

```
sujan@LenovoX1:/mnt/c/Users/Jan/Documents/foo$ xdg-open ./Preview.html
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /us
r/bin/run-mailcap line 528.
Couldn't find a suitable web browser!
Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 771: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening './Preview.html'
```

Thinking about it, this makes sense: There is no browser available inside WSL.

Can I somehow set this `BROWSER` variable so `see` works inside `bash` of WSL?

---

Bonus question: If yes, how can I make the ruby script work *without* changing that code? It's an external dependency :/

Answer (score 81):

Install [wslu](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) and add `export BROWSER=wslview` to your `$HOME/.bashrc` (or equivalent if you use other shell)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! :)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This should probably be marked as the answer-- this is preinstalled on Ubuntu as a part of ubuntu-wsl and shipped by canonical engineers. You can see a blog post about it here: https://ubuntu.com/blog/new-installation-options-coming-for-ubuntu-wsl. While setting the `$BROWSER` envvar does in fact also solve this problem, using `wslview` allows for predictable bridging between the WSL and Windows environments.

I usually also reference https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL first with anything specific to Ubuntu as it's frequently updated.

Comment: You still have to set `export BROWSER=wslview` in _.bashrc_ or _.profile_ or similar. You can on Ubuntu start the default browser with `wslview` or ` xdg-open`. I think the answer should make that clear but otherwise nice answer @ParamSiddharth!

Comment: Unfortunately this setting does not work for `xdg-open` with a file as an argument like `xdg-open index.hml`. In this case Windows' `Start` gets the Linux path in the original form: `The system cannot find the file specified.` ... `+ Start "/home/user/tmp/index.html"`

Comment: `wslview` needs to run powershell, which is extremely slow - urls open with a delay of seconds on my computer. `explorer.exe` on the other hand is instantaneous and opens the url using your default browser as per your Windows settings.

Comment: @buzzedword Unfortunately since Ubuntu 22.04 `wslu` is not installed by default. https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu/issues/233

Comment: .. also attempting to install wslu on 22.04 seriously fubar'd my system.

Answer (score 42):

You can set the `BROWSER` variable. There is a [long article explaining how to set environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

If you want to set the variable for the current terminal session you can use:

`export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/Firefox/firefox.exe'`

(assuming you want to use Firefox and have it installed in `C:\Program Files\Firefox\firefox.exe`)

If you want this to be [persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables), you can add the above line to the file `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually tell me how to open the file after setting the `BROWSER` env variable...

Comment: I had to add \ before the whitespace in the path string for this to work.

Comment: This didn't work for me as it's directly using linux path, e.g. file:///tmp/cover688282190/coverage.html

Answer (score 27):

For some reason WSL can see the windows file explorer. If you do:

```
explorer.exe Preview.html
```

in the console it should open in the default Windows web browser.

Comment: it only opens the Documents folder in Windows explorer for me

Comment: Try to quote the link/path to the webpage like `explorer.exe "./Preview.html"`

Comment: At least at time of writing the path translation between WSL and explorer.exe is very finicky. In my experience it hardly works at all on WSL volumes and will arbitrarily not work on Windows volumes.

Answer (score 21):

I used
`sensible-browser http://localhost:8001/` on Ubuntu 20.04 w/ WSL2

Comment: This answer should get all the upvotes. No need to configure anything. It just works!

Comment: explorer.exe: command not found

Comment: This answer works.

Comment: This does not work in Ubuntu 22.04 / WSL2 (without setting anything): *Couldn't find a suitable web browser!
Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.*

Comment: Worked for me today on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 installed via PowerShell `wsl --install -d Ubuntu` command

Answer (score 13):

Combining the two answers above, the simplest solution is to set BROWSER to windows file explorer in order to use the default Windows web browser

```
export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe'
```

Comment: I like that idea, but when I call `xdg-open https://www.google.com` my Firefox for Windows open two tabs with google, while it is only one tab when I execute `explorer.exe https://www.google.com`. Any idea on how to get only one tab via xdg-open?

Comment: I have the same problem as @Holger any updates on a fix?

Comment: using `update-alternatives --install "bin/host_chrome" "chrome" "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" 1` followed by `export BROWSER=host_chrome` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 10):

Building on the prior answers

`export BROWSER=/some/path/to/chrome.exe` is likely the solve you are looking for, however chrome's default path is `/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe` (a path with spaces and parens for the shell to escape). This works fine if the application uses the a quoted version of the variable `"${BROWSER}"` will successfully open chrome. However if you use the variable unquoted `$BROWSER`, bash will consider it as individual variables. This breaks in some tools, such as `xdg-open`.

working around this is simple, you can symlink it to a path with out spaces.

```
ln -s "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" ~/.local/bin/chrome
export BROWSER=~/.local/bin/chrome
```

Alternatively, you can use `update-alternatives` as [Brett](https://superuser.com/questions/1262977/open-browser-in-host-system-from-windows-subsystem-for-linux#comment2294313_1352293) pointed out. In the end, this is also a symlink, but has slightly more visibility for when/if you need to update where the link points.

```
update-alternatives --install "bin/host_chrome" "chrome" "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" 1
export BROWSER=host_chrome
```

Comment: This helped me, but I needed to set the absolute path to the link target `/home/username/.local/bin/chrome` to be able to launch the browser. Now I'm able to launch Chrome from Hyper and from the terminal in VS Code. 

Also see this post regarding chrome tmp files: might be useful if you are running karma tests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090298/karma-use-windows-chrome-from-wsl

Comment: did not work for me. It complains that "alternative link is not absolute as it should be". So it is missing a forward-slash for `"bin/host_chrome"`. Should be `"/bin/host_chrome"`. However the browser opens, but it does not open the URL in question. Just the blank start page.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a "poor man's" `open` from macOS for WSL:

`alias open="powershell.exe /c start"`

Add that to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` as appropriate, or run it in your WSL shell, and then the following things will work:

```
open . # opens current folder in Explorer as e.g. \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\john\myapp
open foobar.txt # opens in notepad.exe
open README.md # opens in VSCode in Windows, for example
open http://example.com # opens in your default web browser in Windows
open Preview.html # opens in your default web browser in Windows, as file://wsl%24/Ubuntu/home/john/Preview.html
```

Downside: this only seems to work with relative paths, not absolute paths

It would be nice if someone made a shell script to emulate [the macOS version](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html), like `-a` for application, `-e` for editor, `-R` to reveal in explorer.exe, etc... and make it work with absolute paths

Comment: to convert between Windows and WSL path simply use `wslpath`

Answer (score 4):

### x-www-browser

Set the default browser of `x-www-browser` like this:

```bsh
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
There are 3 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/wslview                30        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/16626

Then you can update the browser priorities like this:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser <browser-path> <priority_as_integer>
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/620983/1507914

### xdg-open

Set the default browser of `xdg-open` by creating a file `/usr/share/applications/wslview.desktop` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=WSLview
Exec=wslview %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
```

and then running this:

```bsh
xdg-settings set default-web-browser wslview.desktop
```

Source: https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu/issues/214#issue-1069341444

Answer (score 3):

After reading different solutions here and other forums,
having the same issue with error

```
xdg-open: no method available for opening [url]
```

to my amazement, what worked for me under my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
install on WSL2 is

```
sudo apt install wslu
sudo apt upgrade
```

then tried the "open" (xdg-open) command one more time and it just worked. In other words, it opened the default browser on my windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Under **WSL2**, you only need to install `xdg-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y xdg-utils
```

Then open any page you want with:

```
xdg-open https://superuser.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Run following commands in WSL**

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum install wslu
export BROWSER=wslview
```

*If your default browser is not **firefox** then you will have to create a **symbolic link** to make it work.*

```
ln -s "/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe" ~/.local/bin/firefox
export BROWSER=~/.local/bin/firefox
```

*Persist this setting, add the following line to ~/.bashrc  **~/.bash_profile** at the end.*

*Use vim, vi or nano editor of your choice.*

`export BROWSER=~/.local/bin/firefox`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without installing anyhting.

First open your browser and open `file://wsl.localhost/` and lets just say you want to open `Ubuntu-20.04` then you can change that URL to `file://wsl.localhost/Ubuntu-20.04/`

you can take a list of what you can access with `file://wsl.localhost/` and its name on `powershell` or `cmd` with command `wslconfig /l`.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure helps you in WSL2:

Open `~./bashrc`

```bash
nano ~./bashrc
```

Add the following command to the end of the file.

- If you use Firefox:

```bash
export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
```

- If you use Google Chrome:

```bash
 export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
```

Now, save the file and close it. Then run the following command:

```bash
source ~./bashrc
```